# Does the review queue keep track of time spent on a review item?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Do the review queues track how much time it takes a reviewer to act on a review task? If so, is that information available in a report of some sort (e.g. Average amount of time spent on each review task)? I, personally, would be interested in seeing my own numbers.

Perhaps this information can also be used for audits (if it isn't already), by throwing more audits up for those trying to click through review tasks as quick as possible.

Comment: Already used for audits and review bans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do the review queues track how much time it takes a reviewer to act on a review task?

Yes.

> is that information available in a report of some sort?

No.

> Perhaps this information can also be used for audits (if it isn't already)

> [Already used for audits and review bans.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289604/does-the-review-queue-keep-track-of-time-spent-on-a-review-item/289605?noredirect=1#comment173713_289604)
>
> –  Shog9♦

Comment: Good enough for me. 'Tis a shame though, I like statistics!